# Add icon sets to an existing excel file with python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to add some icon sets to an existing excel file using python.
The excel file is written using xlsxwriter. As xlsxwriter does not support icon sets, I close the file, reopen it with openpyxl, add the icon sets and save it again. Problem is, that I loose all conditional formatting added previously. Opening the file in openpyxl with "keep_vba=True" results in a non-readable xlsx-File.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: Missed some details. Sorry for that. I write xlsx files in both cases (xlsxwriter and openpyxl) and use python 2.7 and the latest versions of openpyxl and xlsxwriter on a windows machine with excel 2013. Icon sets are little symbols like arrows (up, down) which can be used in conditional formatting.

Comment: So, you converted your **xls** file to **xlsx**, right? What do you call "icon sets", can you give us an example?

Comment: I only work with xlsx files. No xls involved. Icon sets are e.g. the traffic lights you can add to a cell: [link](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Use-data-bars-color-scales-and-icon-sets-to-highlight-data-F118D0A6-5921-4E2E-905B-FE00F3378FB9)

Answer (score 1):

OpenPyXl has a support for conditional formatting and Icon Sets.

See the official documentation: [Conditional Formatting > IconSet](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/formatting.html#iconset)

Here is an example:

```
>>> from openpyxl.formatting.rule import IconSet, FormatObject
>>> first = FormatObject(type='percent', val=0)
>>> second = FormatObject(type='percent', val=33)
>>> third = FormatObject(type='percent', val=67)
>>> iconset = IconSet(iconSet='3TrafficLights1', cfvo=[first, second, third], showValue=None, percent=None, reverse=None)
>>> # assign the icon set to a rule
>>> from openpyxl.formatting.rule import Rule
>>> rule = Rule(type='iconSet', iconSet=iconset)
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't describe the problem well: The conditional formatting added with openpyxl works just fine and I see the icon sets. But all other conditional formats which were in the original file are lost.

Comment: It sounds like a bug in OpenPyXl :-(

Comment: I've been afraid of that. Thanks for your help and time!

Comment: Why should it be a bug in openpyxl? Could be something else. Anyway. I wouldn't try and mix the two libraries like this. Probably makes more sense to create the file in openpyxl.